# How to split the object into two according to it's own data in array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, javascript-objects

I was given a case to split the array of object according to it's own quantity of the object data

Case 1:

```
const product = [{
    product_sku: 'p1',
    product_qty: 2,
  },
  {
    product_sku: 'p2',
    product_qty: 1,
  }, ,
  {
    product_sku: 'p3',
    product_qty: 2,
  },
]
```

Expected Outcome:

```
const product = [{
    product_sku: 'p1',
    product_qty: 2,
  },
  {
    product_sku: 'p1',
    product_qty: 2,
  },
  {
    product_sku: 'p2',
    product_qty: 1,
  }, ,
  {
    product_sku: 'p3',
    product_qty: 2,
  },
  {
    product_sku: 'p3',
    product_qty: 2,
  },
]
```

The outcome of the result will depend on the iteration of its own quantity of product

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried and what you're struggling with specifically in your attempt? That way you can see where you're going wrong

Comment: why do you keep the quantity?

Comment: @NickParsons i try to so many ways like map, filter but i was unable to get the exact answer, i'm so sorry since i'm newbie of javascript, i was expect to someone to give guidances on it

Comment: @NinaScholz it doesn't matter just a reference for it

Comment: @OscarChuaWeiWen If you're new to JS, I would suggest creating an empty array `[]` and using a plain `for` loop to loop over the items (objects) in your array, and then use an inner `for` loop to loop `product_qty` times, and use `.push()` on your current object (that way you can clearly see how your code functions and where the loops are, unlike using something like `.map` or `.flatMap` that abstracts that). You also might want to copy the object before you push it. It would be good to see the `map` of `filter` attempts (this also shows that you've put some effort/research into your question)

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @OscarChuaWeiWen Can I know why you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and create a nested array with the wanted amount of copies of the object.

```js
const
    products = [{ product_sku: 'p1', product_qty: 2 }, { product_sku: 'p2', product_qty: 1 }, { product_sku: 'p3', product_qty: 2 }],
    result = products.flatMap(product =>     // map a new flat array
        Array.from(                          // create a new array
            { length: product.product_qty }, // with a defined length and
            () => ({ ... product })          // map new object
        )
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code.

```js
const product = [
    {
      product_sku: 'p1',
      product_qty: 2,
    },
    {
      product_sku: 'p2',
      product_qty: 1,
    },
    ,
    {
      product_sku: 'p3',
      product_qty: 2,
    }
  ];

  let outProduct = [];

  product.forEach(el => {
    for (let index = 0; index < el["product_qty"]; index++) {
      outProduct.push(
        {
          product_sku: el["product_sku"],
          product_qty: index + 1
        }
      );
    }
  })

  console.log(outProduct);
```

Comment: This is not the correct output as per the author expectation.

Answer (score 1):

oen way can be to have an intermediate result array to stored duplicate data

variable in js are reference to duplicate your object in new array you can use `structuredClone({yourObject})`

```js
const product = [{
    product_sku: 'p1',
    product_qty: 2,
  },
  {
    product_sku: 'p2',
    product_qty: 1,
  }, ,
  {
    product_sku: 'p3',
    product_qty: 2,
  },
];

var result = [];
product.forEach(one => {
  Array(one.product_qty).fill(0).forEach(fake => {
    result.push(structuredClone(one));
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
const product = [{
  product_sku: 'p1',
  product_qty: 2,
}, {
  product_sku: 'p2',
  product_qty: 1,
}, {
  product_sku: 'p3',
  product_qty: 2,
}];

const res = [];

product.forEach((obj) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.product_qty; i++) {
    res.push(obj)
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const product = [
        {
            product_sku: 'p1',
            product_qty: 2,
        },
        {
            product_sku: 'p2',
            product_qty: 1,
        },
        {
            product_sku: 'p3',
            product_qty: 2,
        },
    ];
    
    
    const multiple_Products = product.reduce((acc, { product_sku, product_qty}) => {
        acc.push(Array(product_qty).fill({product_sku, product_qty}))
        return acc;
    }, []);
    console.log(multiple_Products.flat());
```